# Query Formula on Sheets Not Working In Excel

Tags: excel

I have a Google Sheet in which I mirror data that meets specific criteria from the main tab to various other tabs using =query and it works! But when I try to use the same exact formula in the same exact sheet in Excel, I return a #NAME? error. Is there an Excel-friendly formula I can use to do the same thing?

The sheet is comprised of a main tab called LeadList which, just as it sounds, is a list of a bunch of leads for potential sales. Column G is a Y/N (yes/no) column indicating if the item was sold. If a cell in Column G says Y, I want that whole row to show up on the next tab, titled SOLD. This was achieved in Sheets using the following formula pasted into the first available cell in the SOLD tab:

=query(LeadList!A5:J,"Select * Where G='Y'",0)

[Here is a picture of the spreadsheet in Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QG27.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets and Excel are not the same product. Google sheets has functions that don't work in Excel and vice versa.

Excel does not have an equivalent to the Google sheets "query" function.